# How do I loop through some XML data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I've been struggling with this for a good 2.5 hours and could really use some help. There can be any number of ATTACHMENTS included and I'm trying to pull out the FILENAME and DESCRIPTION from each. Here's my code *(excuse the mess)* I would greatly appreciate any help you can give. Thanks!

```
DECLARE
   @myXML XML = NULL
  ,@hDoc  INT = 0
  ,@Num   VARCHAR(2)
  ,@Type  VARCHAR(5)
  ,@FileName    VARCHAR(32) = ''
  ,@Description VARCHAR(256) = '';

SET @myXML = '
<REPORT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DESCRIPTION="TestOrder" FILENUM="1234">
    <ADDENDA>
        <ATTACHMENTS>
            <ATTACHMENT NUM="1" TYPE="1">
                <FILENAME>4215.pdf</FILENAME>
                <DESCRIPTION>Sales Contract</DESCRIPTION>
                <CONTENT>...</CONTENT>
            </ATTACHMENT>
            <ATTACHMENT NUM="2" TYPE="1">
                <FILENAME>6719.pdf</FILENAME>
                <DESCRIPTION>Contract Instruction</DESCRIPTION>
                <CONTENT>...</CONTENT>
            </ATTACHMENT>
        </ATTACHMENTS>
    </ADDENDA>
</REPORT>';

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @myXML;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Begin get required docs 
DECLARE xDocsCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT    *
  FROM OPENXML (@hDoc, '/REPORT/ADDENDA/ATTACHMENTS/ATTACHMENT',1)
          WITH ([NUM]  varchar(32),
                [TYPE] varchar(5))
          WHERE [NUM] IS NOT NULL;
OPEN xDocsCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM xDocsCursor INTO @Num, @Type;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @Num, @Type;
  -------------------
  FETCH NEXT FROM xDocsCursor INTO @Num, @Type;
END
CLOSE xDocsCursor;
DEALLOCATE xDocsCursor;
-- End get required docs /REPORT/TRACKING/REQUIREDDATA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why don't you switch to newer cleaner native XQuery instead of old-fashioned `OPENXML()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the **native XQuery** support in SQL Server to do this - much simpler, less messy than the legagy `OpenXML` approach:

```
SELECT
    Num = XAttachments.value('@NUM', 'int'),
    [Type] = XAttachments.value('@TYPE', 'int'),
    FileName = XAttachments.value('(FILENAME)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    Description = XAttachments.value('(DESCRIPTION)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM 
    @myxml.nodes('/REPORT/ADDENDA/ATTACHMENTS/ATTACHMENT') AS XT(XAttachments)
```

Produces output of:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this did exactly what I wanted it to do with a minimal amount of coding. Thank you very much for taking your valuable time to help me out!

Comment: @marc_s, could I ask how your answer significantly differs from mine?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your `OPENXML`:

```
SELECT    *
FROM OPENXML (@hDoc, '/REPORT/ADDENDA/ATTACHMENTS/ATTACHMENT',1)
      WITH ([NUM]  varchar(32),
            [TYPE] varchar(5),              
            [FILENAME] VARCHAR(25) './FILENAME',
            DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) './DESCRIPTION',
            CONTENT VARCHAR(50) './CONTENT')
      WHERE [NUM] IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm not quite sure why you want to use a `CURSOR` here, as you can get the rows returned this way in a single table for manipulation/query.  If you prefer the 'modern' XQuery format, here it is (this would not require running `sp_xml_preparedocument`, and should perform better).

```
SELECT x.value('@NUM', 'VARCHAR(32)') as NUM
      ,x.value('@TYPE', 'VARCHAR(5)') as TYPE
      ,x.value('./FILENAME[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS FILENAME
      ,x.value('./DESCRIPTION[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS DESCRIPTION
      ,x.value('./CONTENT[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS CONTENT
FROM @myXML.nodes('/REPORT/ADDENDA/ATTACHMENTS/ATTACHMENT') T(x)
```

Comment: I was using a CURSOR because I was so frustrated I was trying anything. Thanks for your help. Your answer of course worked. Again, I really appreciate it!